# MFC - how can i add a spin control to list control

Tags: mfc, listcontrol

I'm new in MFC, implementing an application where i want to allow user to enter number and for that i want to show spin controls inside list control.

is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks in a column, you'll need to dynamically create an edit control with an associated spinner within the extents of the CRect of the column.  When the user clicks off the edit control, destroy the edit control.  This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235278/An-MFC-CListCtrl-derived-class-that-allows-other-c) should provide some insight.